# How should we call a company's fiscal year?

Tags: financial-statements

A fiscal year is any 12-month period that the company uses for accounting purposes.
If a company's fiscal year is the same as the calendar year, it is simple determine its fiscal year.
A financial report covers from *2020/1/1* till *2020/12/31*. It is called *2020* year's financial report.

If a company's fiscal year is from *4/1* till *3/31* on next year, and a financial report cover from *2020/4/1* till *2021/3/31*, is it called *2020* year's financial report or *2021* year's financial report?

If a company's fiscal year is from *9/1* till *8/31* on next year, and a financial report cover from *2020/9/1* till *2021/8/31*, is it called *2020* year's financial report or *2021* year's financial report?

If a company's fiscal year is from *12/1* till *11/30* on next year, and a financial report cover from *2020/12/1* till *2021/11/30*, is it called *2020* year's financial report or *2021* year's financial report, then?

Comment: When forming a company, one can choose to use which ever fiscal year they wish.  Some prefer Jan, others September.  Some, because of the fast moving nature of their business might choose a different month because that is the month they started.

Answer (score 11):

Typical nomenclature would be to refer to the calendar year of the *last month of a company's fiscal year*.

ie: A company with a year going from April 1 2021 to March 31 2022, would typically call that year "2022".

To remove confusion with a 'regular' Jan 1 2022 - Dec 31 2022 year, some people would refer to that as "*fiscal* 2022", or perhaps "year ended 2022" or in longest form removing all doubt "year ended Mar 31 2022".

Comment: Or "2021/2022 fiscal year".

Comment: In the case referred to above, I'm (US) used to seeing "FY 2022".

Comment: Yes any or all of the above also are common.